# Virtual keyword and libraries

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, virtual, libraries

as usual thanks in advance...

I have the class `Base`, and the class `Thing` which are both defined in `base.lib`

The `Base` class has a protected virtual function `createThing()` which as you might guess creates and returns an instance of a `Thing`

Now; I also have another project, let's call it "Garage".

In this project, I have the class `Garage` which (publicly) derives from `Base`. I also create the class `Car` which derives from `Thing`.

In `Garage`, I override `createThing()` to return an instance of a `Car`.

OK.

Here's where it gets complicated.

`Base` in my case actually creates a worker thread (I've tried both putting the threads body as a private member of `Base`, as a member of a seperate class).

Within that worker thread, `createThing()` is called through a pointer like so:

```
Thing* thing = base->createThing();
```

Which is fine and dandy when testing `Base` by itself.

However, as soon as I make a new project and link to `base.lib`, creating my `Garage` and `Car` classes as described, the line above always calls the constructor for `Thing` and never for `Car`

Could somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Edit: In this example (and in my actual code), the variable `base` DEFINATLY points to an instance of `Garage`

Another test I've just tried, if I cast my `Garage` (created on the stack) to a `Base` pointer, then call `base->createThing()`, it works as expected.

It is only when I let the worker thread call `base->createThing()` that I get this problem

Comment: Clearly *base* is a pointer to Base, not Garage.  Very hard to see how it could ever be an instance of Garage.  There's also nothing in your question that suggests you made sure it was.

Comment: Are you sure you used the virtual operator on createThing() and are you sure base is pointing to an instance of Garage and not Base?

Comment: Yeah `base` is a pointer to `Base`, I read somewhere that polymorphism should kick in since it is a pointer and I'm not calling it from another member or from the object directly?

Comment: base can be of type Base *, but the object it actually points to has to actually be a Garage.  For example:  Base * ptr = (Base *) new Garage()  creates a Base * ptr that points to a Garage (though a garage is also a Base).  You need to make sure the object is actually a Garage

Comment: And yes I'm absolutely sure I used the virtual operator - I was not aware that if I work with a `Base` pointer that it would call `Base::createThing()`; I thought it would call the derived function unless I explicitly tell it to call the parent one; isn't that the point of virtual? That functions on a parent object can call functions on a derived class without the parent being aware of the derived classes' existance?

Comment: sedavidw - The variable `base` in this example is *definatly* pointing to an instance of `Garage`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this myself to close the question, as I am beginning to think this is some kind of linking issue or unrelated problem. All the comments were much appreciated, thanks!!

EDIT: Totally deleting the project and starting again worked, I cannot imagine what the issuse was but presumably some odd bug in VC++

Thanks all!